# -s meaning in plain english

Tags: python, command-line

I am struggling to understand the meaning of -s in python. I have checked the documentation, https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/cmdline.html, but I just cannot understand what the answer means.

I do not understand the motivation for using it.

I dont understand what "Path to the user site-packages for the running Python" is. Nor do I understand exactly how sys.path works in correspondence with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have permissions to install packages under the directory of the Python distribution (ex: regular user under Linux/Unix with no root permissions) you may install the packet in your own HOME directory under:

- ~/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages

(Note: if you are not a regular Unix/Linux user: `~` stands for your `HOME` directory)

When you run a Python script and do:

```
import package_x
```

The above directory will have been added to `sys.path` and if the package has been installed under that directory will be found and imported

If you run with `python -s` the same script then:

- The above directory will not be added to `sys.path` and the `import package_x` will fail

To install to your USER directory use: `pip install --user package_x`

The installation directories per OS can be found under:

- https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE

EDIT:

- Motivation (one of many): you have your own package which happens to be installed along the main Python distribution. You can also install a newer version as a **user package** and switch amongst version with `python` and `python -s`

The `user site directory` comes before the `site directory` when searching for packages